# anti-forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I've got my logoff link:

```
<a id="lnkLogoff" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> @Resources.LogOff</a>
```

When link is pressed it submits my logoff form:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Logoff", "Account")" id="logoutForm">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

This works great 99.9% of the time. But I ran into an issue when I submit a form, it goes in to the controller and it returns the model back to the view displaying toaster messages on the result. Once it's returned there, all of my AntiFOrgeryTokens seem to be missing or invalid, or something.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public PartialViewResult PersonUserOpen(UserPageModel model)
        {
            model.Function = DataFactory.SystemAccess.GetFunction(model.Function.Id);

            if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Roles.Any(a => a.IsGranted))
            {
                //This is valid, do stuff and add success message
            }
            else{
                 //add Error messages to be displayed
             }

             return PartialView(model);
}
```

After displaying the view again with its messages, all of the form's anti forgery tokens are either missing or invalid, not sure. So when I post this view's form or click logoff to post the logoff form they don't work because it's missing the anti-forgery token.. What's up with this? This page is for updating user's passwords stored in UserManager, could this be related to the problem? In the HttpGet method of the controller I add the user being changed to the model:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(person.ApplicationUserId);

                model.MembershipRoles = DataFactory.SystemAccess.GetMembershipRoles(user.Id);

                model.User = new UserViewModel
                {
                    Id = user.Id,
                    Email = user.Email,
                    Username = user.UserName,
                    Active = user.Active
                };
```

Comment: I know this is an old questions, but did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm facing a similar issue with missing tokens. Everything works fine on initial page load and I'm able to POST, but if I refresh the partial view data and try to POST again I get a message saying the token isn't present.

Comment: Ahhh yes, blast from the past. I did get it to work, I think it was something to do with forcing it to get a new antiforgery token. Maybe building up a new page model  or just forcing it to rebuild the page instead of just returning the same stale model back with a view. I no longer work where that code was written, so I can't take a peak. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond to my _shot in the dark_ question. Much appreciated.

I was hoping to get away with not having to refresh the whole page, but it seems like it might be my only option. I'll give it a whirl and see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, too. After examining I found that I have to move the `<script>` part to the outer view, otherwise another form will be nested in the old form... not sure why, feeling very strange.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).